# How to generate feature containing date types and date format?

Tags: 7, features

I have created new date types and date formats using Drupal 7 UI. But I can't generate feature for both of them (format and type). Only format is available in [Strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) but type isn't. Please tell me how to generate feature for both of them.

Answer (score 0):

There is another option: hardcode the date format in the preprocessor. And print it in the node you are using. In this way it is in your code base and you do not need to have it in your feature.